# XML Injection attacks

Tags: c#, xml, security, xpath

What is the best way to prevent XML injection attacks? I want to use parameterization, but there is nothing like SQL, so I have to build one. I'm just wondering what's the best way to build one, and what should I be cleansing.

### Update

Sorry, it is for XPath. I am writing a quick function to remove all single and double quotes right now, but is there a better way?

Comment: Could you provide some more detail? (What is the XML being used for, are you using XPath, etc)

Comment: Can we see some code? Might help provoke an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many XPath processors/APIs allow you to use variables in your expression, so you can write for example `//A[@status=$param]` where the value of `$param` is supplied by the calling code. If you can use that, do, because it prevents all injection attacks. It's also likely to be more efficient than constructing an expression using string concatenation, because it only needs to be compiled once.

Comment: And for prevention in wcf ria services is any way preventing from xml destroying created by a request?

Comment: If you have a question, ask it as a question, not as a comment on an answer to a different question posted 9 years ago. I have no idea what "wcf ria services" are, so  I'm not the person to ask anyway.